# Has anyone built a declarative tool builder or 4gl app on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 4gl

We have been seeing how productive you can be building apps in technologies like salesforce declaritive tools (builder) where you can create entities, relationships, views, validations, triggers, workflow, and reporting all without writing a line of code. If need be, you can also write custom code for the custom features. This is great for folks with salesforce licenses or for those committed to the platform.

For those outside this environment I was thinking we could build something similar using ruby on rails, but before I begin was wondering if anyone has already built something like this?